# Form becomes slow through many checks

Tags: javascript, php, html, barcode

We have an application with which we scan barcodes from shipping carriers and store them in a database.

The shipment numbers have different lengths. We check the characters with Javascript and send a form as soon as a certain number of characters have been recognized. There are a total of 10 different barcodes that must be recognized.

The problem will be that when scanning, each character is inserted very quickly one after the other, resulting in a large number of queries.

If many consignment numbers are scanned one after the other, it always becomes slow and it takes 5-10 seconds until the form is reloaded.

Do you have an idea how the process can be improved?

```
$(function() {
  var $id = $('#input_field');
  $id.keyup(function(e) {
    if ($id.val().length == 9 || $id.val().length == 12 || $id.val().length == 13 || $id.val().length == 14 || $id.val().length == 18 || $id.val().length == 19 || $id.val().length == 20 || $id.val().length == 26 || $id.val().length == 27 || $id.val().length == 28) {
      $(this.form).submit();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It feels like a [debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce) function would be useful here, where you can specify some period of time between when the function specified can be called (thus allowing for time between 'keystrokes' before submitting).